# Error while Implementing Kuali Curriculum Management

Tags: java, maven, kuali

**I am following [this link](https://wiki.kuali.org/display/STUDENTDOC/KS+Curriculum+Management+2.0+QuickStart+Installation+Guide#KSCurriculumManagement2.0QuickStartInstallationGuide-Introduction) to get this Kuali Project Done.**

**However i am getting below error while running below command:**

```
mvn validate -Pks-db,oracle -Dks.impex.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<db host>:<port>:<SID> -Dks.impex.dba.password=<SYS password>
```

**Error:**

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.4:execute (validate-dba-config)
>   on project ks-cfg-dbs: The parameters 'driver', 'url' for goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.4:execute are missing or invalid
>   -> [Help 1]org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.4:execute
>   (validate-dba-config) on project ks-cfg-dbs: The parameters 'driver',
>   'url' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.4:execute are
>   missing or invalid        at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:220)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
>   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
>   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
>   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)        at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)        at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)        at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)        at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)        at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)Caused
>   by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterException: The parameters
>   'driver', 'url' for goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.4:execute are missing or invalid

Please help me out in this regard, let me know if i need to provide any other information.

Thanks!
Application Team

Comment: Have you installed driver? This part `The parameters 'driver', 'url' for goal` suggest that DB driver is missing.

Comment: Read the error message. *The parameters 'driver', 'url' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.4:execute are missing or invalid*

Comment: Yeah, i checked this error, however i don't know what driver i need to install. I have done whatever installation doc says. Can you put some more light, Maven is new for me. Thanks!

Comment: Does it mean, DB Driver where i am trying to connect to DB is not working?